# Generic Class and Method

Tags: java, generics, pagination, playframework

I'm working on a pagination system for my java project, and I'd like to make it generic for my various JPA Models.

The problem (as far as I know) is that if I use generics, I will have to somehow cast the returned final value to work on it. How can I avoid that ?

Here's my code so far (absolutely not generic!) :

```
public interface Paginator {
    public void setLimit(Integer limit);
    public Page page(Integer page);
}


public class PicturesPaginator implements Paginator {
    private Integer limit = 10;
    private JPAQuery query;
    private Long quantity;

    public PicturesPaginator(String query, Object... params) {
        this.query = Picture.find(query, params);
        this.quantity = Picture.count(query, params);
    }

    @Override
    public void setLimit(Integer limit) {
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    @Override
    public PicturesPage page(Integer page) {
        if (page == null)
            page = 1;

        List<Picture> pictures = query.fetch(page, limit);
        return new PicturesPage(pictures, quantity, page, limit);
    }
}


public abstract class Page {
    protected List<Picture> pictures;
    protected Long quantity;
    protected Integer page;
    protected Integer limit;

    public List<Picture> list() {
        return pictures;
    }

    public Long count() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return (page * limit > quantity);
    }

    public boolean hasPrevious() {
        return (page != 1);
    }

    public boolean hasOtherPages() {
        return (hasNext() || hasPrevious());
    }

    public Integer nextPageNumber() {
        if (!hasNext())
            return null;

        return (page + 1);
    }

    public Integer previousPageNumber() {
        if (!hasPrevious())
            return null;

        return (page - 1);
    }

    public Integer currentPageNumber() {
        return page;
    }
}


public class PicturesPage extends Page {
    public PicturesPage(List<Picture> pictures, Long quantity, Integer page, Integer limit) {
        this.pictures = pictures;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.page = page;
        this.limit = limit;
    }
}
```

I would like to get rid of those `PicturesPaginator` and `PicturesPage` and make it generic, but the `list()` method from the abstract class Page would return a generic List (`List<T>` or `List<GenericModel>` since I use Play here).
What I would expect is this `list()` method to return the correct List, aka `List<Picture>` in my case. Is this possible ?

Note: I now there is a module for pagination in Play! Framework, my question is mainly for understanding more about java too :)

Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can view my Play--Pagination module's source code to see how I handle this type of thing.  I put my [source on github](https://github.com/lmcalpin/Play--Paginate).

What you want to do is make Page generic as well, and probably non-abstract:

```
public class Page<T> {
  public List<T> list() {}
}
```

And instead of PicturesPage you could just do:

```
new Page<Picture>()
```

The Paginator interface would also need to be generified:

```
public interface Paginator {
    public Page<T> page(Integer page);
}
```

Generifying PicturesPaginator would be harder since you invoke methods on the Picture class.  Java's generics implementation erases types at runtime, so you'll have to deal with type tokens and reflection.

```
public abstract class GenericPaginator<T> {
  public GenericPaginator() {
    Class<T> typeToken = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    // use reflection to invoke the finders methods
  }
}
public class PicturesPaginator extends GenericPaginator<Picture> {}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't understand what you saw that I use from the Picture class : I only use items from JPA (find & count). But  finally, I upgraded my code to allow generic Classes using T extends GenericModel and I have a problem : the `Class<T> typeToken = ...` throws this error : `java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Re: Picture class, I was referring to the class methods find and count which Play! provides for you.  Re: ClassCastException -- I would assume you didn't make the PicturesPaginator like I described above, with a subclass that extends a generic base class, providing a parameterized type (the "class PicturesPaginator extends GenericPaginator<Picture>" is an example of that). An alternative approach would be to just add a Class<T> typeToken method parameter to the constructor for GenericPaginator.

Comment: You assumed correctly! :) I tried to move everything into one Class, moving the content of PicturesPaginator to Page. I finally decided to add the work directly into my model, and call Page with those parameters : JPAQuery (result of find()), Long (result of count()). It's not neat, but at least it works. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

> What I would expect is this list() method to return the correct List,
>   aka List in my case. Is this possible?

That's not just possible, that's what you automatically get if you use generics correctly. If you declare

```
public class Page<T extends GenericModel>{
    protected List<T> items;

    public List<T> list() {
        return items;
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
page = new Page<Picture>();
```

then `page.list()` will in fact return a `List<Picture>`, because `T` is a *type parameter* that is replaced by a concrete type when a `Page` is declared.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, the following may help:

Make Pace generic. Turn

```
public abstract class Page {
    protected List<Picture> pictures;

    public List<Picture> list() {
        return pictures;
    }
```

to:

```
public abstract class Page<Element> {
    protected List<Element> elements;

    public List<Element> list() {
        return elements;
    }
```

Than make PicturesPage concret:

```
public class PicturesPage extends Page<Picture> {
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you require, but you can convert the Page class to this:

```
public abstract class Page<T> {
    protected List<T> pictures;
    protected Long quantity;
    protected Integer page;
    protected Integer limit;

    public List<T> list() {
        return pictures;
    }

    public Long count() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return (page * limit > quantity);
    }

    public boolean hasPrevious() {
        return (page != 1);
    }

    public boolean hasOtherPages() {
        return (hasNext() || hasPrevious());
    }

    public Integer nextPageNumber() {
        if (!hasNext())
            return null;

        return (page + 1);
    }

    public Integer previousPageNumber() {
        if (!hasPrevious())
            return null;

        return (page - 1);
    }

    public Integer currentPageNumber() {
        return page;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, your problem with introducing generics here are lines like this:

```
this.query = Picture.find(query, params);
```

AFAIK you can't invoke static methods on generic types directly, so you'd have to use reflection here. In that case you might have to pass the class of the parameter type as a parameter (or get it from reflection data if it exists), find the method you want to invoke and invoke it.

It's something like this:

```
 Class<T> clazz;

 public Paginator (Class<T> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;

    //note that you need to handle exceptions, I'll leave them out for brevity
    Method findMethod = clazz.getMethod("find", String.class, Array.class ); 
    this.query = findMethod.invoke(null, query, params);
 }
```

*Edit*

As an alternative, pass a "finder" object to the generic `Paginator` and make it implement an interface that provides the `find(...)` and `count(...)` methods:

```
interface Finder<T> {
  JPAQuery find( String query, Object... params);
  Long count( String query, Object... params);
} 

class Paginator<T, F extends Finder<T>> {
  public Paginator(F finder, String query, Object... params) {
    this.query = finder.find(query, params);
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```